# Devise + Polymorphic association questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, polymorphic-associations

I'm fairly new to Rails, and having an issue understanding where I'm missing something.
I'm using Rails 4, Devise and I have a main `User` model that holds just `password`, `email`, and `user_name` that are common fields to my additional models: `Artist`, `Fan`. 
I have the relationships set up as so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name 
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :account, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class Fan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :account, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

And there is also one model that `belongs_to` `Artist`:

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

I have managed to get the polymorphic connections working, creating an Artist and it's user on creation. Now I am trying to create the `Artist/Track` connection.Currently I'm a getting it to 
create the new Song, but it's not making the association on create. I'm getting a Track with no associated `Artist_id = nil`

My Song Controller looks something like this:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
 before_action :set_track, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
   @track = Track.new
   @track.build_artist
  end

 def create
   @track = Track.new(track_params)
   if @track.save
    flash[:notice] = "Track was successfully created."
    redirect_to @artist 
   else
    redirect_to new_artist_track_path
   end
  end
```

Also... after successful create `redirect_to @artist` gives me an ActionControllerError of
"Cannot redirect to nil!

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: solved the `redirect_to` issue with changing `redirect_to @artist` to

```
redirect_to artist_path(current_user)
```

Still can't figure out how to save the association with Artist in Track on create

Edit #2: Here is my `track_params`

```
def track_params
  params.require(:track).permit(:track_title, :description, :track_type)
end
```

Edit #3:
Here's the form:

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_for @track, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :track_title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :track_title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :track_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :track_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the following is the log after create:

```
Started POST "/tracks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-10 00:03:08 -0600
Processing by TracksController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",          "authenticity_token"=>"TzzOJrRmCzAcqdJcm+X5vSfKoHiL36T/yqUsdrpP+Ew=", 
"track"=>{"track_title"=>"Track", "description"=>"Test track ", "track_type"=>"Demo"},    "commit"=>"Create Track"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 (0.0ms)  begin transaction SQL (261.5ms)  INSERT INTO "tracks" ("created_at", "description", "track_title",  "track_type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-07-10  06:03:08.377238"], ["description", "Test track "], ["track_title", "Track"], ["track_type",  "Demo"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-10 06:03:08.377238"]] (45.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/artists/1
Completed 302 Found in 312ms (ActiveRecord: 306.9ms)
```

Comment: Can you post your `track_params method`? And you have to include `accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist` in `Track` model.

Comment: @Pavan edit#2 above has my track_params method, I don't have accepts_nested_atributes_for :artist on my Track model as everything I read regarding how to make an association, nothing mentioned that, is that required? My two models as they are above.

Comment: Can you post your `form code` where you creating the `track`? And also posting the `server log information` on `form submit` would be helpful.

Comment: @Pavan see edit #3 above. I have a devise User class as you can see about that is used for Devise authentication, it has made it much more of a pain in the behind for sure. The form is multipart to accommodate a Paperclip upload which is being added later.

Comment: You don't have any input for `artist_id` in your form,then how do you expect it to save?

Comment: @Pavan it's not needed, the association is connected in the controller

Comment: No,the association only relates the models,you have to pass a value to `artist_id` in order to save it.

Comment: so my question is.. what am i missing?

Comment: You should most likely adding a `select` or `collection_select` for `artist_id`.This will make a `drop-down` of available `artists`.By selecting an artist from the drop-down,the `artist_id` will be saved to the DB

Comment: @Pavan i think you have not really looked at my question.. these two models are associated and are already connected through Active Record.. thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The @artist member variable is only available on each request, so the instance that you created in the new request is not available in the create request, well technically its nil.  And you don't redirect to the record, but to a route.

Assuming you have the parameters set up correctly, and the association is being made in create, you could redirect to artist_path(@track.artist) but would need to see your routes.rb file to be sure

Comment: I was able to solve the redirect_to @artist by changing to:  redirect_to artist_path(current_user) still can't seem to figure out why the create is not creating the association to Artist

Comment: Now that you have posted more of the params and logs, I don't see any params for the Artist.  The attributes for the artist need to be on the form, since you are using accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: Or is the artist intended to just be the current_user, in which case you don't need to use accepts_nested_attributes_for, but will need to save the artist on the track, which there are several ways to do, but need to understand your intentions first.

Comment: User is the Devise class handling just the authentication for the 3 different user types. Artist, Fan, accept nested attributes from User, Track belongs_to Artist, Artist has_many Tracks so yes when a new Track is saved it needs to be related to the current_user or Artist that is creating it. You can only create a Track as the current logged in Artist

Comment: OK, that's not how accepts_nested_attributes_for works.  The idea for accepts_nested is that the form has the fields for the model that you specified with accepts_nested.  You might want to add an after_create callback to the Track model to set the Artist.  See answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can set the artist to the current user in the controller after the create

```
def create
  @track = Track.new(track_params)
  if @track.save
    self.update_attributes(artist: current_user)
    flash[:notice] = "Track was successfully created."
    redirect_to artist_path(@track.artist) 
  else
    redirect_to new_artist_track_path
  end
end
```